# Source code appears with apache, why repare?

Tags: php, linux, apache, server

I own a site installed on my linux server but when I put PHP tags at the beginning of page, the source code appears..

How to avoid all the source code displayed ?

thank you in advance

Comment: PHP is not being used to handle the request. This could be for a number of reasons. Follow through with an installation guide.

Comment: apache is serving you the php page without having it pre-processed by php

Answer (score 2):

This means that you are being served the file by Apache without it first being seen (processed) by PHP. Here are some troubleshooting tips as to why it isn't being processed by PHP:

- Make sure that your file with the PHP tags ends in `.php`.
- Make sure PHP is installed on your server. To install PHP on a debian server run `sudo apt-get install php5`

Comment: Problem is resolved! I not have installed PHP5 on my server. Sorry!

Comment: @Aymeric98 seriously? lol